# Get a ftp remote directory listing sorted by creation date in python?

Tags: python, ftplib

How to get sub directory list from ftp location sorted by created date. i use following code. but it's sort by name

```
import ftplib

def sortFTPDir(dirpath):
    f = ftplib.FTP(ip, username, password)
    try:
        f.cwd(dirpath)
        nameList = f.nlst()
        print "Sorted Directory List : ", nameList
        for p in range(len(nameList)):
            print nameList[p]

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

    finally: 
        f.close()
```

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete and verifiable example. As written, your code isn't nearly enough to meet those standards.

Comment: import ftplib

def sortFTPDir(dirpath):
    
    f = ftplib.FTP(ip, username, password)
    
    try:
        f.cwd(dirpath)
        nameList = f.nlst()
        
        print "Sorted Directory List : ", nameList
        
        for p in range(len(nameList)):
            print nameList[p]
    
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
                
    finally: 
        f.close()

Comment: I think you'll find updating the post itself, with all the nice code formatting, would look a lot more pleasant than in the comments :)

Comment: can you have a look :)